# Cannot redirect to error Page in ReactJS although I added Link tag

Tags: reactjs

```
const data = instance.get(url).catch((error) => {
  if (error.response) {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
      <Link to="/error">
        <ErrorPage err={error.response.data} />
      </Link>;

      console.log("Page Not Found");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you are using react router dom, you need to use the `Redirect` component

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: You should read the RRD documentation, there is plenty of good examples of how to redirect, both programatically and with the redirect component. You should also read the docs on react hooks too

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect a user from this kind of implementation. The [link tag](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) is like an anchor tag in HTML. So what you have to do is you need to programmatically redirect the user. For that, you can [use history hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory).

> The implementation is something like this.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();
 

 const data=instance.get(url).catch((error)=>{ if(error.response){

   if(error.response.status===404){               
           console.log("Page Not Found");
           history.push("/error");
       }
 }
```

Comment: I got following error : Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.